# ThreeJS static text animations

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js

I was hoping that [ThreeJS](https://threejs.org/) has some way of animating text besides on top of a plane. I would prefer to animate the text as 2D and just floating above a model. I attempted to use divs outside of the canvas, but that was having issues pointing to the correct place and still remaining responsive.

I want it to look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzGaz.png), while animating the line underneath the text.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is you want to create a 2d canvas and use that as the texture, something like this

```html
var canvas1 = document.createElement('canvas');
var context1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
context1.font = "Bold 40px Arial";
context1.fillStyle = "rgba(255,0,0,0.95)";
context1.fillText('Hello, world!', 0, 50);

// canvas contents will be used for a texture
var texture1 = new THREE.Texture(canvas1) 
texture1.needsUpdate = true;

var material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {map: texture1, side:THREE.DoubleSide } );
material1.transparent = true;

var mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.PlaneGeometry(canvas1.width, canvas1.height),
    material1
  );
```